# Stanza has non-deterministic results

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, stanza

I started using multiple documents processing and found out I start receive different results for single documents, depending on the documents batch I put them in.

A code which can illustrate it (I can't use my real data):

```
in_docs = ...
doc_index = 10  # chosen randomly
result_from_batch = nlp(in_docs)[doc_index]
result_as_single_doc_request = nlp(in_doc[doc_index:doc_index+1])[0]
assert len(result_from_batch.sentences) == len(result_as_single_doc_request.sentences)
```

I want to emphasize that (as far as I experienced) a documents batch will always receive the same deterministic result, but single documents may receive different results depending on the batch the are put in.

Is this behavior known and expected?
Does stanza support a way to ensure deterministic result?

Comment: What are "results"? Are these token objects? Sentence objects? What does it mean for the results to be "equal"?

Comment: I use it for dependency parsing model, so for example a document is sometimes parsed into 1 sentence, and sometimes into 2 sentences with different DP words and different entities.

Comment: Is that what that object's `__eq__` method actually compares?

Comment: I updated the code above to answer that question. The documents I get back by the model is completely different, the amount of sentences sometimes change.